# firebase_crashlytics - what triggers the upload of the report?

Tags: flutter, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I'm using `firebase_crashlytics 0.1.1+2`
to capture my crashes.  I'm trying to test my crashlytics implementation.  What triggers the sending of the Crashlytics report and why does it not always appear in my console?

Sometimes the `Crashlytics report upload complete` message shows immediately and at other times it doesn't seem to show at all.  Also, even though the complete message shows sometimes it never shows in my console and its appearance seems a bit random

```
I/flutter (28064): Flutter error caught by Crashlytics plugin:
I/flutter (28064): Error reported to Crashlytics.
I/CrashlyticsCore(28064): Crashlytics report upload complete: xxxxxxxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

*(whilst writing the above, I figured out the below)*

Sometimes I receive a crash report in the Crashlytics consol and sometimes it never appears but the following seems to increase the odds of getting a crash report sent through

- If I use `flutter run` it seems to work
- To get the report complete message I change focus from intellij to
  another screen (this seems strange)
- Only if I do a hot restart will the report be sent to the console (if
  I quit the run in the terminal then the report never gets sent)
- Make sure the correct project and the correct app are selected inside
  Firebase (I initially chose the wrong app!)